# What is the concept of doing payment timer and payment gateway?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm new in building payment system. I want to do a system with payment process. One of those payment methods is using Paypal. How to do the payment process with payment timer and also the payment gateway.

If the user complete the payment right after the timer time up, what will happen and how to prevent this ?

After selecting the payment method, user will click the "book" button. Then it will be redirect to a page with payment timer and show the Paypal payment interface. How the timer will start and the Paypal interface popup ? Below are the conditions need:

1. Time over, Paypal popup window close and redirect to error page.
2. Payment failed, timer stop and redirect to error page.
3. Payment done, timer stop and redirect to success page.

Comment: I don’t think the PayPal popup will let you interact with in any way, that would make 1. possible. And in general, this question seems rather broad. I don’t know if PayPal itself offers any such functionality (like specifying a time stamp until which the payment has to be made, otherwise considering it a failure) - you’d have to consult their documentation. If not, I guess the most you can do, is check after a successful payment, whether it was still within your specified time frame, and if not, cancel the transaction again directly.

Comment: For your information, I have create a database table to store the info. The end time and other info will save into the database after user click 'book' button. The reason I create the timer is to remind the user complete the payment within the time given.

So what payment method can I choose to match with the timer ? Online banking ?